# How do I get my Model inclusive filled fields back from view to controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

How do I get my Model inclusive filled fields back from view to controller without loosing the fields.

My model has three fields:

```
myModel.setId(1);
myModel.setName("MyName");
myModel.setStatus("MyStatus");
```

In my first Controller I set `myModel` in a model:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/spiel/{spielId}/runde/{rundenNummer}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(Model model){
    MyModel myModel = new MyModel(1, "MyName", "MyStatus");
    model.addAttribute("myModel", myModel);
return "index";
```

I use myModel in the view and want to post it via a form.

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/index/update/}"  
                 method="post" th:object="${myModel}">
```

In my second Controller I want to reuse myModel inclusive the previous filled attributes.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index/update}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(Model model, @ModelAttribute("myModel") MyModel myModel){
    myModel.getId(); // should be 1
    myModel.getName(); // should be "MyName"
    myModel.getStatus(); // should be "MyStatus"
return "update";
```

How can I achive this behaviour in the view? Do I need hidden input fields for all attributes of myModel? Or is there an easy way to sent back the same model back?

Comment: To use a quote from *the Matrix*, *there is no model*. You need to pass the fields and spring will recreate the `MyModel` class from that.

Comment: @M.Deinum Means `myModel` is accessible in the view in with all attributes of it but for sending it back to controller I can not use `myModel`. Have to set hidden input fields for all attributes of `myModel` for example.

Comment: Correct... You have to pass the fields around (or if it something from a database, you can do a lookup based on the id, which you still need to pass of course).

Comment: @M.Deinum ok, thank you. And yes, this is what I already do. (db lookup)

Comment: Then you can just pass the id and do a lookup. If it is the same controller you could use `@SessionAttributes` to store it in the session (temporarily)!. But there is too little information on what you are trying to achieve :)

Comment: @M.Deinum At the end I wanted all information of `myModel` in the view and also all information of `myModel` back in my other controller. Only using the post method and `th:object="${myModel}"`. And maybe with updated values. Wondering why I loose the information in the second controller. The view has full access of `myModel` but cant send it back.